# Преобразование строки в JSON через JSON.parse

Tags: javascript

Я получаю с сервера экранированную строку в виде:

```
"{\"username\": \"admin\", \"City\": \"\", \"Age\": null, \"Image\": \"/images/static/imagination/cb8b8fc3-b450-4338-80b5-c8a1b93ec58a_yb8VU8b.jpg\", \"Sex\": \"M\"}"
```

Далее я преобразую эту строку через `JSON.parse` в надежде получить объект javascript, но получаю только неэкранированную строку:

```
{"username": "admin", "City": "", "Age": null, "Image": "/images/static/imagination/cb8b8fc3-b450-4338-80b5-c8a1b93ec58a_yb8VU8b.jpg", "Sex": "M"}
```

Я не нашел среди [описания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) этой функции подобного поведения.

Далее я обнаружил, что если второй раз применяю JSON.parse, то получаю объект, как и хотел изначально. Тестировал в Chrome.

Является ли такое поведение нормальным (соответствует стандарту?) и стоит ли применять JSON.parse для первого преобразования?

Comment: Скорее всего сервер криво формирует ответ, дважды делает JSON.stringify (ну или аналог в соответствующем ЯП).

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы применить JSON.parse(), вы должны передать в качестве аргумента текст в формате JSON. А вы передаете не совсем в формате JSON.
Но вам везет, и обработчик парсит и выводит это уже в формате JSON. Если вас не смущает дважды вызывать parse, и во всех случаях работает корректно - почему бы и нет?

Comment: Мне кажется, объяснения на уровне "вам везёт" автору недостаточно

Comment: Явно об этом не говорится, поэтому ждем автора вопроса.
Здесь, думается, вполне можно использовать принцип утиной типизации.